# Find Empty values between column range in the table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table as shown in the screenshot. The expected result is highlighted with colouring.

[image]

I have 6 columns which are the stages of a process from 1 to 6.
Say the user skipped a process then the values will be empty but there are values for the next stage(coloured in blue). If there are no values in the subsequent stage then they are empty (coloured in green) I want to differentiate between the green and blue values.
I mean column value is b if it is empty  and has next stages(there are values in subsequent columns).
Column values is g if it is empty and doesn't have next stages(no values in subsequent columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a lengthy CASE expression for this. You can shorten it a little by using `COALESCE` and `IIF`, both of them are converted to CASE expressions:

```
SELECT
COALESCE(col1, IIF(col2 IS NULL AND col3 IS NULL AND col4 IS NULL AND col5 IS NULL AND col6 IS NULL, 'g', 'b')) AS col1,
COALESCE(col2, IIF(                 col3 IS NULL AND col4 IS NULL AND col5 IS NULL AND col6 IS NULL, 'g', 'b')) AS col2,
COALESCE(col3, IIF(                                  col4 IS NULL AND col5 IS NULL AND col6 IS NULL, 'g', 'b')) AS col3,
COALESCE(col4, IIF(                                                   col5 IS NULL AND col6 IS NULL, 'g', 'b')) AS col4,
COALESCE(col5, IIF(                                                                    col6 IS NULL, 'g', 'b')) AS col5,
COALESCE(col6, 'g')                                                                                             AS col6
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use giant case expressions:

```
select (case when col1 is null and (col2 is not null or col3 is not null or col4 is not null or col5 is not null or col6 is not null)
             then 'b'
             when col1 is null
             then 'g'
             else col1
        end) as col1,
       (case when col2 is null and (col1 is not null or col3 is not null or col4 is not null or col5 is not null or col6 is not null)
             then 'b'
             when col2 is null
             then 'g'
             else col2
        end) as col2,
       . . .
from t;
```